# iPhone hot spot keeps dropping

Tags: iphone, wifi

In my quest to get working internet at our cottage I installed a 5-band cell booster, which took our average reception from 1 bar to 3. We now have steady connections for voice and data on the phones.

However, when I use the hotspot feature to connect my laptop, it drops continually. This *appears* to be timed: it happens every 5 minutes or so. I can easily reconnect, but only after unlocking the phone.

Is this typical behavior?

Comment: It’s not typical behavior.  I would test your hotspot when you’re in an area where you don’t need the booster/repeater.  See what the results are so we can eliminate the repeater from the equation or not.

Comment: According to posts on Apple's sites, the system will turn off after 15 minutes of no activity.

Comment: Just as a guess: This may be due to your "booster". I've had hotspot connections up and running for hours. I have to use a booster in my place also, and seen some spotty behavior. But I've not tried a hotspot connection while the phone is linked through the booster because my booster requires Internet connection via Ethernet... yours doesn't I suppose?